# Datatable JQuery stateSave - recolocar filtros

Tags: jquery, datatable, filtro, table, busqueda

Estoy siguiente un ejemplo para generar un datatable con un campo search en cada una de las cabeceras de la tabla, de forma que cuando actualice la página almacene las busquedas (con statesave).

Ahora mismo funciona, pero los cuadros de busqueda estan en la parte inferior de la tabla y los quiero cambiar a la cabecera, debajo del nombre de la columna.

Os dejo el código:

Esta es mi tabla de prueba:

```
<table id="prueba" class="display" width="100%">
               <thead>
                   <tr>
                       <th>Campo1</th>
                       <th>Campo2</th>
                       <th>Campo3</th>
                       <th>Campo4</th>
                       <th>Campo5</th>
                       <th>Campo6</th>
                   </tr>
               </thead>
               <tfoot>
                   <tr>
                       <th>Campo1</th>
                       <th>Campo2</th>
                       <th>Campo3</th>
                       <th>Campo4</th>
                       <th>Campo5</th>
                       <th>Campo6</th>
                   </tr>
               </tfoot>
               <tbody>
                   <tr>
                       <td>Prueba1</td>
                       <td>Prueba1</td>
                       <td>Prueba1</td>
                       <td>Prueba1</td>
                       <td>Prueba1</td>
                       <td>Prueba1</td>
                   </tr>
                   <tr>
                       <td>Prueba2</td>
                       <td>Prueba2</td>
                       <td>Prueba2</td>
                       <td>Prueba2</td>
                       <td>Prueba2</td>
                       <td>Prueba2</td>
                   </tr>
                   <tr>
                       <td>Prueba22</td>
                       <td>Prueba3</td>
                       <td>Prueba4</td>
                       <td>Prueba5</td>
                       <td>Prueba3</td>
                       <td>Prueba4</td>
                   </tr>
                   <tr>
                       <td>Prueba5</td>
                       <td>Prueba6</td>
                       <td>Prueba7</td>
                       <td>Prueba8</td>
                       <td>Prueba9</td>
                       <td>Prueba2</td>
                   </tr>
               </tbody>
           </table>
```

Este es el Jquery:

```
<script>
//Codigo JQuery donde definimos todo el funcionamiento de refresco de página, filtros y datatable
$(document).ready(function() {
   // Setup - add a text input to each footer cell
   $('#prueba tfoot th').each( function () {
       var title = $('#prueba tfoot th').eq( $(this).index() ).text();
       $(this).html( '<input type="text" placeholder="Search '+title+'" />' );
   } );

   // DataTable
 var table = $('#prueba').DataTable( {
   bFilter: true,
   bAutoWidth: true,
   sDom:"ltipr",
   bInfo: false, 
   ordering: false,
   orderCellsTop: false,
   bPaginate: false,
   fixedHeader: false,
   stateSave: true
 } );
 
   // Restore state
   var state = table.state.loaded();
   if ( state ) {
     table.columns().eq( 0 ).each( function ( colIdx ) {
       var colSearch = state.columns[colIdx].search;
       
       if ( colSearch.search ) {
         $( 'input', table.column( colIdx ).footer() ).val( colSearch.search );
       }
     } );
     
     table.draw();
   }
   

   // Apply the search
   table.columns().eq( 0 ).each( function ( colIdx ) {
       $( 'input', table.column( colIdx ).footer() ).on( 'keyup change', function () {
           table
               .column( colIdx )
               .search( this.value )
               .draw();
       } );
   } );
} );
</script>
```

¿Alguien me puede echar una mano? He probado todo lo que se me ha ocurrido, pero no hay manera... mil gracias!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mira de realizar estos cambios a ver si así te funciona como deseas:

1. Cambia esto:

```javascript
$('#prueba tfoot th').each( function () {
       var title = $('#prueba tfoot th').eq( $(this).index() ).text();
       $(this).html( '<input type="text" placeholder="Search '+title+'" />' );
   } );
```

por esto:

```javascript
 $('#prueba thead th').each( function () {
       var title = $('#prueba thead th').eq( $(this).index() ).text();
       $(this).append( '<input type="text" placeholder="Search '+title+'" />' );
   } );
```

2. Y elimina esto del HTML:

```html
<tfoot>
  <tr>
    <th>Campo1</th>
    <th>Campo2</th>
    <th>Campo3</th>
    <th>Campo4</th>
    <th>Campo5</th>
    <th>Campo6</th>
  </tr>
</tfoot>
```

Como ya ves en las diferencias de ambos códigos, se trata de agregar los inputs de búsqueda con `append` en lugar de sustituir el texto existente, y apuntar a la cabecera `thead` en lugar del pie `tfoot`.

Aquí te dejo un snippet de ejemplo de como te va a quedar:

```js
//Codigo JQuery donde definimos todo el funcionamiento de refresco de página, filtros y datatable
$(document).ready(function() {
   // Setup - add a text input to each footer cell
   $('#prueba thead th').each( function () {
       var title = $('#prueba thead th').eq( $(this).index() ).text();
       $(this).append( '<input type="text" placeholder="Search '+title+'" />' );
   } );

   // DataTable
 var table = $('#prueba').DataTable( {
   bFilter: true,
   bAutoWidth: true,
   sDom:"ltipr",
   bInfo: false, 
   ordering: false,
   orderCellsTop: false,
   bPaginate: false,
   fixedHeader: false,
   stateSave: true
 } );
 
   // Restore state
   var state = table.state.loaded();
   if ( state ) {
     table.columns().eq( 0 ).each( function ( colIdx ) {
       var colSearch = state.columns[colIdx].search;
       
       if ( colSearch.search ) {
         $( 'input', table.column( colIdx ).footer() ).val( colSearch.search );
       }
     } );
     
     table.draw();
   }
   

   // Apply the search
   table.columns().eq( 0 ).each( function ( colIdx ) {
       $( 'input', table.column( colIdx ).footer() ).on( 'keyup change', function () {
           table
               .column( colIdx )
               .search( this.value )
               .draw();
       } );
   } );
} );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.11.4/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.11.4/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

<table id="prueba" class="display" width="100%">
               <thead>
                   <tr>
                       <th>Campo1</th>
                       <th>Campo2</th>
                       <th>Campo3</th>
                       <th>Campo4</th>
                       <th>Campo5</th>
                       <th>Campo6</th>
                   </tr>
               </thead>
               <tbody>
                   <tr>
                       <td>Prueba1</td>
                       <td>Prueba1</td>
                       <td>Prueba1</td>
                       <td>Prueba1</td>
                       <td>Prueba1</td>
                       <td>Prueba1</td>
                   </tr>
                   <tr>
                       <td>Prueba2</td>
                       <td>Prueba2</td>
                       <td>Prueba2</td>
                       <td>Prueba2</td>
                       <td>Prueba2</td>
                       <td>Prueba2</td>
                   </tr>
                   <tr>
                       <td>Prueba22</td>
                       <td>Prueba3</td>
                       <td>Prueba4</td>
                       <td>Prueba5</td>
                       <td>Prueba3</td>
                       <td>Prueba4</td>
                   </tr>
                   <tr>
                       <td>Prueba5</td>
                       <td>Prueba6</td>
                       <td>Prueba7</td>
                       <td>Prueba8</td>
                       <td>Prueba9</td>
                       <td>Prueba2</td>
                   </tr>
               </tbody>
           </table>
```

Comment: Wow!! es justo lo que necesito, mil gracias!! una ultima duda, en las ultimas filas los filtros no funcionan. Es decir, si filtro el campo4 por "Prueba8", me indica que no hay coincidencias. ¿sabes a que puede deberse? Mil gracias por tu ayuda!

Comment: La verdad es que no he entrado al detalle de si funcionaban o no los filtros.  Todo deberia funcionar como antes, yo tan solo he movido las ubicaciones de esos inputs como puedes ver en la respuesta. Quizás deberias abrir otra pregunta con ese problema para conseguir más ayuda. Si esta respuesta satisface tu pregunta inicial, márcala como aceptada para que la comunidad lo sepa y no quede pendiente para siempre, gracias.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda!!